# How to connect FaceBook SDK with cocos2d

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-ios-sdk

As we all know face book is providing SDK to add face book in our applications.

In simple applications it's easy to add such SDK as all things are known, but how to add FaceBook SDK in cocos2d applications.

I am new to this thing, so if any one can help me out, how to add FaceBook SDK with cocos2d?

I've done the same in simple applications, but I am not able to work with cocos2d.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3392 , here is some examples and also code how to connect face book in cocos2d. It will help full to you.